# Power BI circular dependency

Tags: powerbi

in my Table , there is already a calculated column CC and an Index ;
I want to calculate a new column DR :

```
DR = 
var c_c = Table[CC]
var d_r = 100 - c_c
return if (Table[Index]=1, 100, d_r)
```

I get the message
A circular dependency was detected: Table[CC], Table[CC], Table[CC].

Any hint, please?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share your code for cc and index column?

Comment: cc = var crt_index var end_dat